# How to get php/html file lines with php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a file manager and I want to add an option of editing files (`html`,`php`,`css`), but if I try with `fgets()` it displays the page and its graphic. How to get only lines from file and then send them as response to ajax request.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('/location/', "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        echo $line;
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
?>
```

Comment: first don't use fgets. Better way is to check if file exists and then do a [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Look up [XMLHttpRequest](http://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/XMLHttpRequest) for better understanding of ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 
`show_source("/location/file.php");` to get the source code.

You can refer it from [W3School - PHP show_source() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_show_source.asp)

Comment: I like this one but when I display it in textarea this happens: <code><span style="color: #000000">
<span style="color: #0000BB">&lt;?php...

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on the same server you can use

```
$content = @file_get_contents($filename);
if($content){
  echo $content;
}else{
   echo 'File:"'.$filename.'" couldn\'t be found.';
}
```